# Liquibase changeset changeLogPropertyDefined - multiple properties

Tags: java, liquibase

In liquibase I have a changeset i'm trying to run on condition of an env property being set, in this case buildEnv, which I pass in with `-DbuildEnv=lcl` for example.  I have this at the top of my changeset:

```
<property name="env" value="${buildEnv}" dbms="oracle" />
```

Then down below I have:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <changeLogPropertyDefined property="env" value="lcl, sit, ppte, prod"/> 
</preConditions>
```

The problem is that this doesn't seem to be working as an OR check.. If I pass in 'lcl' above I would expect it to get executed, instead I get the message:

```
Expected changelog property 'env' to have a value of 'lcl, sit, ppte, prod'.  Got 'lcl'
```

Any ideas how this could be fixed or possibly be done in a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an [`<or>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html#andornot-logic)

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
  <or>
    <changeLogPropertyDefined property="env" value="lcl"/> 
    <changeLogPropertyDefined property="env" value="sit"/> 
    <changeLogPropertyDefined property="env" value="ppte"/> 
    <changeLogPropertyDefined property="env" value="prod"/> 
  </or>
</preConditions>
```

Comment: Thanks alot mate :)